# Shorten segment to certain length

Tags: geometry

Let's say I have a line segment defined by the points $P_1$ and $P_2$, how would I change the length of the segment to length $n$ by moving $P_2$ closer/further from $P_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you want a point $P$ such that $P$ is on the **half line** $P_1P_2$ and $P_1P=n$.

Suppose that $P_1(x_1,y_1),P_2(x_2,y_2)\ (P_1\not= P_2)$ are given. Every point on the half line $P_1P_2$ can be expressed as 
$$((1-t)x_1+tx_2,(1-t)y_1+ty_2)$$
for $t\ge 0\in\mathbb R$.
Hence, solving
$$n^2=((1-t)x_1+tx_2-x_1)^2+((1-t)y_1+ty_2-y_1)^2$$
gives us
$$t^2=\frac{n^2}{D^2}\Rightarrow t=\frac{n}{D}$$
where $D=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.
Hence, the point $P$ you want can be expressed as
$$P\left(\left(1-\frac{n}{D}\right)x_1+\frac nDx_2,\left(1-\frac{n}{D}\right)y_1+\frac nDy_2\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, but I'm a bit confused on how to calculate what D is

Comment: @phoenix: $D$ is the distance between $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was n, then how would I calculate n?

Comment: @phoenix: ?? $n$ is the length you want, isn't it? In other words, you can(have to) decide the $n$ such that $P_1P=n$. For example, if you want $P_1P=2$, then set $n=2$ in the coordinate I wrote in my answer.

Comment: OH I understand now, I'm sorry, I was confusing p1p2 with p1p, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$ I suppose that you want the coordinates of a point $P= (x,y)$ at distance $n$ from $P_1$ on the line passing through $P_1$ ansd $P_2$ .  If so, the you want the solution of the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=n^2\\
y-y_1=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)
\end{cases}
$$
where the first equation fix the distance and the second is the stright line.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_1=(x_1,y_1), P_2=(x_2,y_2)$. I assume you want to find a point $P_3=(x_3,y_3)$ such that $P_3$ is on the line $P_1P_2$ and $P_1P_3=n$. There are two such points.

Create a circle defined by the curve $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=n^2$. The intersections of this curve and the line $P_1P_2$ will give you the coordinates of the wanted point $P_3$.

$P_1P_2$ is defined by $\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. Now solve $$\begin{cases}(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=n^2\\\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\end{cases}$$

$$\iff (x-x_1)^2+(x-x_1)^2\frac{(y_2-y_1)^2}{(x_2-x_1)^2}=n^2$$

$$\iff x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{1+\frac{(y_2-y_1)^2}{(x_2-x_1)^2}}}+x_1$$

$$P_3=\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{1+\frac{(y_2-y_1)^2}{(x_2-x_1)^2}}}+x_1,\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{1+\frac{(y_2-y_1)^2}{(x_2-x_1)^2}}}\right)\left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)+y_1\right)$$

If you want $P_3$ to be on [the ray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#Ray) from $B$ to $A$, then choose the $P_3(x_3,y_3)$ such that if $x_2-x_1=t(x_3-x_1)$, then $t>0$.

Since $$(x_2-x_1=t(x_3-x_1))\iff (y_2-y_1=t(y_3-y_1)),$$ we can also check: if $y_2-y_1=t(y_3-y_1)$, then $t>0$.